# HTML Move DIV Tags Freely on the Page

Tags: html, tags, move

This is kind of off the wall but is it possible to have a webpage where the user can move the content within DIV tags freely around the page?

The internet doesn't have much information about it but surely it's possible.

For example if I have a list of DIV's I can basically drag and drop divs within the page as I want them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support browsers without HTML5, [jQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) does exactly that.

Assuming you have a unique way to identify every container, you could use the `stop` event to iterate through your draggable elements and index them. Then it's up to you to save those container/index pairs in a cookie or database.

Bonus: Use [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to make it work on touch devices.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know if it's possible to "save" the position of the draggable item using a cookie or with using usernames do you?  That'd be ideal.  But this is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: how would using the stop event be able to save the position of the item?  Is it able to give a number for the position on the page that I can put in the databases?  Thanks for your help this is really great content!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Draggable by itself doesn't keep an index, I meant hook into the stop event and then at that point you can iterate through your draggable items and define indexes yourself.